# Possible to speed up image loading in php/imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I've noticed that loading an image into imagick (`$im = new Imagick($sFilename);`) in php is taking 0.6 seconds for an 8MB image.  This seems a bit slow to me, so I tried a test and read the file in using `file_get_contents` instead.  About 0.005 seconds.  Better.  A bit too good tbh, I guess there's some caching going on there?

But I can load the same file a dozen times into imagick and it's always ~0.6 seconds.

Can I tell file_get_contents to bypass the system cache somehow, to give me a better idea of the raw speed with which an 8MB file can be retrieved from my hard drives?

Is there anything that can be done to speed up imagick?  Or is 0.6 seconds for this operation completely normal?

The server has two 7200rpm HP sata drives in RAID 1.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the reason Imagick is slower is because it does some parsing when loading an image. Parsing 8MB of data will take some time.

Comment: It's not the file read that takes a long time, but decoding the 8MB image to a bitmap, possibly quite huge.

Comment: I did wonder that, but it seems a long time for that.  Is there anything that can be configured to give imagick more resources?  Set it as a "high priority" CPU task or something?  Or enable multicore processing, etc?

Comment: What is the type of the image - JPG? PNG? What are the dimensions of the image in pixels? What are you actually trying to achieve - process one image fast, or get through a large number of images in a small time? Are you on Windows?

Comment: JPG, 6000x4000, CentOS 6.7, Xeon E5-1650, 32GB RAM.  Both - sometimes one image, other times thousands.

Comment: Why do you consider the 0.6 a long time to read the specific image into imageMagic? Did you compare it to anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything that can be done to speed up imagick?

Buy a faster CPU

> Or is 0.6 seconds for this operation completely normal?

Yes.

> This seems a bit slow to me
>
> but it seems a long time for that.
>
> I guess there's some caching going on there?

You're just guessing that something should be faster.....and you'r comparing it to a completely different operation. file_get_contents just reads the bytes in the file off the disk. Creating an image from a JPG means the computer has to read the bytes off the disk, and then decode them from the compressed data to be the actual image data.

If you want to see how much work has to be done during the compression, you can easily see this by writing the image out in an uncompressed format e.g.

```
$imagick = new Imagick("./testImage.jpg");
$imagick->setImageFormat('BMP');
$imagick->writeImage("./output.bmp");
```

And yes, this is longer than is reasonable for a HTTP request to take processing. Which is just another reason for why not running Imagick in a webserver is a good idea, but to instead run it as a background task.